# JSTL If condition not working in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I am basically trying to send an arraylist to a JSP page and an if condition in the page determines what value to set as 'selected' in a dropdown.

**Servlet:**

```
public class FeatureServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ArrayList<FeaturePermission> permList = new ArrayList<FeaturePermission>();

        FeaturePermission perm = new FeaturePermission();
        perm.setStatus("2");
        permList.add(perm);

        request.setAttribute("perms", permList); 
        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/CheckData.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

**CheckData.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <select id="check_status" name="check_status">
                <optgroup label="Choose Status">
                    <option value="1" <c:if test="${perms[0].status == 1}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>1</option>
                    <option value="2" <c:if test="${perms[0].status == 2}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>2</option>
                </optgroup>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

**FeaturePermission class:**

```
String ID = "";
String Status = "";

//Getter Setter & Constructors
```

I basically need to check if the value in the parameter 'Status' is equal 1, then set the selected option as 1 and so on for all the choices in the dropdown.

However, when I run it, the correct value is not selected. Is my code correct?

Comment: Nope now it became an empty value. There's nothing inside the choice tag when I run it @josivan

Comment: Can you explain how that works please? Why isn't there a 'if' in that code you gave me? @josivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` and `eq` are the same for string comparison in expression language. but you have to put `'1'` and `'2'` inside `'` marks. like:

```
<option value="1" <c:if test="${perms[0].status == '1'}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>1</option>
<option value="2" <c:if test="${perms[0].status == '2'}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>2</option>
```

Also define `status` field starting with `s` instead of `S`.

Comment: Because they are strings. I might use a word instead of a number sometimes.

Comment: Yes. Since they're `string`, you need to test them like `perms[0].status == `1``

Comment: I got an error when I made your change. It's underlining near the  == "1" part in red giving an error: Encountered "<EOF>", was expecting one of Was expecting one of: <INTEGER_LITERAL> ... <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ... <STRING_LITERAL> ... "true" ... "false" ... "null" ... "(" ... "-" ... "not" ... "!" ... "empty" ... <IDENTIFIER> ...

Comment: Btw, if I use the same principle inside a Jstl for loop, it doesn't work:
<c:forEach items="${perms}" var="perm">
 <option value="${perm.status}" <c:if test="${perms[0].status== '${perm.status}'}"> <c:out value="selected=selected"></c:out></c:if>>${perm.status}</option>

Comment: Shall I post it as a new question? Or shall I edit it in this question?

Comment: One question per post is one of the rules in stackoverflow ... '${perm.status}' doesn't need `'` because it's not a constant string.

Comment: It says: contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing:   ${perms[0].status== '${perm.status}'}. You sure? :)

Comment: Yes. But if you removed `'`s and it still didn't work, consider asking another question.